# Question on SO is labeled as edited by me even though I did not do that

Tags: support, question-lists

I'd like to report following bug (at least I think so).

I'm looking at questions related to `sql-server` tag on Stack Overflow. One of them was answered by me, however it displays me as last editor. Is it expected behaviour? Please see screenshots:

> [image: Me, listed as editor]

And once you open question:

> [image: Just an answer]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"Modified" has a more general meaning than "edited." Think of a modification as any notable change to a question page's state. That means:

- Answering the question
- Editing the question or any of its answers
- Reopening the question
- other things I might have forgotten

In this case, you answering the question changed the state of the page, showing it as modified by you.

Comment: Thank you for explanation. I just thought it was confusing at first, but now it makes sense.

Comment: @Evaldas No problem! Glad to help.

Comment: NOTE: Answering the question will put "answered by ... " in the summary. So you can take that off the list